# Compute stats from a dictionary and populate a new column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Below is a data frame that contains some summary information related to a few records along with a that dictionary contains more detailed information for a subset of those records.  In reality the DataFrame and the dictionary contain thousands of entries but for purposes of simplicity I've limited the entries.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14'],
'count': [10, 10, 10, 9, 9],},
index = ['NNI', 'NVEC', 'IPA', 'LYTS', 'MYN'])

df
            Date  count
NNI   2022-02-14     10
NVEC  2022-02-14     10
IPA   2022-02-14     10
LYTS  2022-02-14      9
MYN   2022-02-14      9

dct = {'NNI' : pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1, -1, -1],
'count': [13, 11, 10]},
index =['2007-07-13', '2019-09-18', '2016-08-01']),
'NVEC' : pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1, -1, -1],
'count': [12, 10, 9]},
index =['2012-10-09', '2018-10-01', '2022-02-01'])
}

dct
{'NNI':        s  count
 2007-07-13   -1     13
 2019-09-18   -1     11
 2016-08-01   -1     10,
 'NVEC':       s  count
 2012-10-09   -1     12
 2018-10-01   -1     10
 2022-02-01   -1      9}
```

My question is:

How can I populate a new column in the DataFrame called `ratio` that searches and matches the keys in the dictionary with the index of the DataFrame and then computes the simple ratio:
`A / B` ?

Preferably looking for a way to accomplish this that does not rely on `for` loops.

where,
`A` = Number of occurrences the dictionary `count` column `>` the value of the DataFrame `count` column for a respective key/index (e.g. for NNI this would be 2),

`B` = Number of occurrences the dictionary `counts` column `>=` the value of the DataFrame `count` column for a respective key/index (e.g. for NNI this would be 3)

So the desired result is:

```
            Date  s  count   ratio
NNI   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.6667
NVEC  2022-02-14 -1     10  0.5000
IPA   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.0000
LYTS  2022-02-14 -1      9  0.0000
MYN   2022-02-14 -1      9  0.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dict comprehension as well. Traverse `dct` and compare values, wrap it in a Series and `assign` it to `df`:

```
df = df.assign(ratio=pd.Series({k: v['count'].gt(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() / v['count'].ge(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() 
                                for k,v in dct.items()})).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
            Date  count     ratio
NNI   2022-02-14     10  0.666667
NVEC  2022-02-14     10  0.500000
IPA   2022-02-14     10  0.000000
LYTS  2022-02-14      9  0.000000
MYN   2022-02-14      9  0.000000
```